# Can you buy Pro-Tools standalone? (software only)

Tags: pro-tools

Can you buy Pro-Tools standalone? (software only)

I have a Mac with a Tascam 144MkII audio IO and MIDI.

Comment: According to [their website](http://shop.avid.com/store/category.do?category=pt10-software), you can.  The question will be whether or not your hardware will work with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [their website](http://shop.avid.com/store/category.do?category=pt10-software), you can.

Your hardware should work with it.  On the Hardware Options page they say:

> **Third-party audio interfaces**
>
> With Pro Tools, you get the flexibility of using the software with practically any audio interface you already have or want. For ultimate quality and performance, choose an Avid interface or bundled hardware/software solution above. Or pair Pro Tools with any other audio interface that supports any of the following drivers:
>
> - ASIO
> - Core Audio

I recommend getting the free 30 day trial and check it out to see if it will work.

Comment: +1 Accepted! "you get the flexibility of using the software with practically any audio interface you already have or want." - Great news I'll check to see if my device supports ASIO and Core Audio. Any thoughts on MIDI? I would have thought it would be easier to support MIDI for most devices owing to the low bit rate and simpler standard. I have looked at prices and they vary - it seems that there are cheaper packages when bundled but not sure if same Pro Tools version, also there is a HD version so would need to figure out these. The free trial recommendation is a great suggestion.

Comment: This is effective, IIRC, since version 9. I personally have not tried running it with a non-Avid device but I've run it without one (just an iLok) and found playback to be buggy. That's 9 though, I'm sure 11 is improved. BTW price-wise you might as well buy the hardware too.